# Laravel - Insufficient data for unserializing - 258 required, 257 present

Tags: php, laravel

I recently deployed my laravel app on a shared hosting (InfinityFree). I already set up my database in phpmyadmin and configured the right credentials in `.env` file.

- All files are currently uploaded in `/htdocs/laravel/` directory
  (except the `public` folder).
- The contents inside the `public` folder was placed in `/htdocs/` directory

Here's the content of my `index.php` that is currently in `/htdocs/` directory:

```
require __DIR__.'/laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

And everytime I open the website (home page) it displays this error:

[image]

The error occurs in **line 22** of `index.php` that is currently on the `/htdocs/` directory. I don't know what causes this error specifically and how to fix this error.

- The PHP version of my server is: 7.4
- Laravel Version of the project:
  8.16.1

Comment: Try [clearing route cache](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-caching)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem you.

I tried running this command `php artisan route:cache`

Answer (score 0):

**This problema tell you some archives from cache are corrupts.**

I resolved this problem with this accions:

- Get inside de /storage/framework/cache/ from the project root

> ***cd storage/framework/cache/***

- Delete all register into data file

> ***sudo rm -R data/***

and voila solved the problem